# Dynamic message lookup and inheritance, who is 'self' referring to in the case of an Object?

Tags: objective-c, oop

I have MyClass inheriting from MyParentClass.

I create an instance of MyClass. When I send a message to this Object and MyClass instance methods doesn't implement it, it goes up the hierarchy to see if MyParentClass instance methods do.

My question is this: If MyParentClass implements this message selector, and inside that message there's a call to [self doWhatever]. will the new selector doWhatever be directed at MyParentClass or at the Object itself and go through MyClass instance methods and then up the hierarchy to MyParentClass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pure OOP question, not Obj-C. And you can test what happens very quickly.

The instance is of the sub class, so any call to 'self' will dispatch to the sub class, even if called in the superclass.

Answer (score 1):

Self will be your object in this instance (not the parent). Therefore, your implementation will be used.